# Android AppCompat ActionBar - Left Align Logo

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, styles, android-toolbar

Within the ActionBar, I am trying to left align the logo and also display the Activity title. I'm finding it difficult to left align the logo.... and also display the logo and the title together.

My Activity is extending AppCompatActivity. I am using the styles.xml to provide the theme to the app. In the styles.xml theme, I have the following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
   <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBarLogoTheme</item>
</style>
```

Which calls the following:

```
<style name="ActionBarLogoTheme" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
   <item name="logo">@drawable/logo</item>
   <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome|showTitle</item>>

   <item name="android:layout_gravity">left</item>
   <item name="android:gravity">left</item>
</style>
```

In the above, the 'gravity' and 'layout_gravity' don't seem to take affect, and also the 'showTitle' display option doesn't seem to take affect also. Would anyone be able to help. The following illustrates what it currently looks like, and what I would like it to look like.

Thank you all.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use an **`ActionBar`** you can use:

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo|showTitle</item>
    <item name="logo">@drawable/....</item>
</style>
```

You can also it programmatically:

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable....);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Title");
```

[image]

But you can also use a **`Toolbar`**:

```
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Gabriele, thank you very much for the above. In all of the options above, I end up with the same conclusion unfortunately. For each of them, my logo is still in the centre of the ActionBar and I can't display the image and text together for some reason. 

If I'm not extending the AppCompatActivity and just extend Activity, and then use a simple AppTheme such as 'android:Theme.Holo.Light' without an extra configuration... it works perfectly. It's just when I use the AppCompatActivity, then try to apply a Theme.AppCompat to the style, it doesn't work.

Comment: @GrahamBaitson I tried my code with `AppCompatActivity` and an `AppCompat` or `MaterialComponents` Theme. I can't understand why your logo is in the center. Post your layout or some related code (are you using a `Toolbar` with `setSupportActionBar()`?

Comment: thank you very much. So when I try the Toolbar is works perfectly... I was just hoping to stay away from having to add additional code, but I can put this into its own layout and include in all my activity layouts. Thanks for your help.